# Make a matrix full-ranked?

Tags: r, matrix

How can I turn a regular matrix into a matrix full-ranked in R? Is there an available method for that?

I have a matrix that may have linearly dependent columns and I need to
pass it to a function that requires its argument to be a matrix with
full rank. Since linearly dependent columns are not of interest
anyway, I am looking for a function that removes such columns until
the matrix is full rank. There may be several solutions of course, but
any one of them should be fine.

Right now I am just constructing the matrix column by column and only
add a column if its the resulting matrix is still fullrank, but it
feels like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: You should really provide more details.  For example if you just always return an identity matrix then you're always turning the 'regular' matrix into a full ranked matrix.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a matrix with independent rows (or columns) that is not square, and you want to create enough additional independent rows (or columns) to make it a square, full-rank, matrix?

Comment: Please define "regular matrix."  And better yet, let us know what the problem is you're trying to solve.  Changing matrix elements to force linear independence is unlikely to be what you want to do.

Comment: The update helps. So now there are two questions. First, how to determine the matrix's rank AND how to identify the offending row(s) if it's not of full-rank.  That requires a bunch of linear algebra (duh) of which I'm no expert.  Second, once the algebraic algorithms are defined, how to implement them in R.  Part 2 is relatively easy.

Comment: Since you don't care which of the dependent columns are removed, a question is begged:  Do you want a matrix with the same column space, or is it required that the columns presented actually come from the input matrix?

Comment: How about a title like "drop linearly dependent columns until a matrix is full-rank" (assuming the second of Matthew Lundberg's cases); *changing* n - r columns to make the rank n is an interesting but quite different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to minimize |y - Ax|<sup>2</sup> + c |x|<sup>2</sup>,
by tacking an identity matrix on to A and zeros to y.
The parameter c (a.k.a. λ)
trades off fitting y - Ax, and keeping |x| small.
Then run a second fit with the r largest components of x,
r = rank(A) (or any number you please).